# Extract form key value pairs form html page in python or parse html page

Tags: python, html, string, parsing, html-parsing

I want to extract key value pairs of some form elements in a html page

for example

```
name="frmLogin" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return validateAndSubmit();" action="TG_cim_logon.asp?SID=^YcMunDFDQUoWV32WPUMqPxeSxD4L_slp_rhc_rNvW7Fagp7FgH3l0uJR/3_slp_rhc_dYyJ_slp_rhc_vsPW0kJl&RegType=Lite_Home"
```

while the original line is

```
<form name="frmLogin" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return validateAndSubmit();" action="TG_cim_logon.asp?SID=^YcMunDFDQUoWV32WPUMqPxeSxD4L_slp_rhc_rNvW7Fagp7FgH3l0uJR/3_slp_rhc_dYyJ_slp_rhc_vsPW0kJl&RegType=Lite_Home">
```

is there any method using which I can safely get the key and value pairs. I tried using splitting by spaces and then using '=' characters but string inside quotes can also have '='.

is there any different kind of split method which can also take care of quotes?

Comment: If you search for the values of the input elements of a form (as opposed to the attributes), then this answer fits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65603777/633961

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a parsing library such as [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) for parsing html.

The library will have a simple way for you to get what you need, probably not taking more than a few steps:

1. load the page using the parser
2. choose the form element to operate on
3. ask for the data you want

Example code:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> doc = lxml.html.parse('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13432626/split-a-s
tring-in-python-taking-care-of-quotes')
>>> form = doc.xpath('//form')[0]
>>> form
<Element form at 0xbb1870>
>>> form.attrib
{'action': '/search', 'autocomplete': 'off', 'id': 'search', 'method': 'get'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions like this one :

```
/([^=, ]+)="([^" ]+|[^," ]+)" ?"/
```

In python, you can do this :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

text = 'name="frmLogin" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return validateAndSubmit();" action="TG_cim_logon.asp?SID=^YcMunDFDQUoWV32WPUMqPxeSxD4L_slp_rhc_rNvW7Fagp7FgH3l0uJR/3_slp_rhc_dYyJ_slp_rhc_vsPW0kJl&RegType=Lite_Home"';

ftext = re.split( r'([^=, ]+)="([^" ]+|[^," ]+)" ?', text )

print ftext;
```

Comment: Escaped double quotes could pose a problem here.

Comment: @JanDvorak I've never seen any quotes escape in HTML, but indeed, it could be a problem...

Answer (score 1):

```
s = r'name="frmLogin" method="POST" onSubmit="javascript:return validateAndSubmit();" action="TG_cim_logon.asp?SID=^YcMunDFDQUoWV
32WPUMqPxeSxD4L_slp_rhc_rNvW7Fagp7FgH3l0uJR/3_slp_rhc_dYyJ_slp_rhc_vsPW0kJl&RegType=Lite_Home"'
>>> lst = s.split('" ')
>>> for item in lst:
...     print item.split('="')
... 
['name', 'frmLogin']
['method', 'POST']
['onSubmit', 'javascript:return validateAndSubmit();']
['action', 'TG_cim_logon.asp?SID=^YcMunDFDQUoWV32WPUMqPxeSxD4L_slp_rhc_rNvW7Fagp7FgH3l0uJR/3_slp_rhc_dYyJ_slp_rhc_vsPW0kJl&RegType=Li
te_Home"']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{i.split('="')[0]: i.split('="')[1] for i in str.split("\" ")}
```

where `str` is your original string

Answer (score 0):

```
dict=eval('dict(%s)'%name.replace(' ',','))
print dict
{'action': 'TG_cim_logon.asp?SID=^YcMunDFDQUoWV32WPUMqPxeSxD4L_slp_rhc_rNvW7Fagp7FgH3l0uJR/3_slp_rhc_dYyJ_slp_rhc_vsPW0kJl&RegType=Lite_Home', 'onSubmit': 'javascript:return,validateAndSubmit();', 'method': 'POST', 'name': 'frmLogin'}
```

This will solve your problem .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library which has support for parsing HTML forms.

For example: https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> Stateful programmatic web browsing in Python. Browse pages programmatically with easy HTML form filling and clicking of links.