# Django: Parse HTML (containing form) to dictionary

Tags: python, django, html-parsing

I create a html form on the server side.

```
<form action="." method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">
 <textarea name="area">long text</textarea>
 <select name="your-choice">
  <option value="a" selected>A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Desired result:

```
{
 "foo": "bar",
 "area": "long text",
 "your-choice": "a",
}
```

The method (`parse_form()`) I am looking for could be used like this:

```
response = client.get('/foo/')

# response contains <form> ...</form>

data = parse_form(response.content)

data['my-input']='bar'

response = client.post('/foo/', data)
```

How to implement `parse_form()` in Python?

This is not related to Django, nevertheless, there is an feature request in Django, but it was rejected several years ago: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11797

## Update

I wrote a small Python library around the the `lxml` based answer: [html_form_to_dict](https://github.com/guettli/html_form_to_dict)

Comment: You'd need to use Selenium to do this.

Comment: @markwalker_ Selenium is needed for paring the html form to a dictionary?

Comment: You're talking about testing your frontend. That's best done with selenium.

Comment: @markwalker_ up to now I like writing tests. I used selenium several years ago, and it was very slow. I would like to keep my edit-test cycle fast. I develop because I like it, not because I must do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just this?:

```
def parse_form(content):
    import lxml.html
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(content)
    return dict(tree.forms[0].fields)
```

I couldn't guess the reason for using a UserDict

**One little caveat**: I noticed that when the form contains a <select>, the first value is returned when no option is selected; the solution I gave above based on BS returns None instead

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I build a small Python library around it: https://github.com/guettli/html_form_to_dict

Answer (score 5):

This is not related to django, just to html parsing.  The standard tool for that is the [BeautifulSoup (bs4)](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library.

It parses arbitrary HTML, and is often used in web scrapers (including my own).  This question covers parsing html forms: [Python beautiful soup form input parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001678/python-beautiful-soup-form-input-parsing), and pretty much everything you'll need is answered on here somewhere :)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def selected_option(select):
    option = select.find("option", selected=True)
    if option: 
        return option['value']

# tag name => how to extract its value
tags = {  
    "input": lambda t: t['value'],
    "textarea": lambda t: t.text,
    "select": selected_option
}


def parse_form(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    form = soup.find("form")
    return {
        e['name']: tags[e.name](e)
        for e in form.find_all(tags.keys())
    }
```

This gives this output for your input:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "area": "long text",
    "your-choice": "a"
}
```

For production, you are going to want to add tons of error checking, for form not found, inputs without name, etc.  It depends on what exactly is needed.

Comment: I guess up to now above snippet does not read the values of textareas and select elements.

Comment: @guettli Sure, it doesn't.  So it can be modified to do that, whats your point?  The only example given is `input`, and if thats whats needed then this is perfectly fine.  Your's seems quite complicated, just use BS and combine a few one-liners to make your ideal dict output. And you could even use lxml as a backend :D

Comment: Maybe you could update your question with a representative input and ouput, otherwise this seems like a strange game you are playing.  For selects, how do you want to handle naming of the output, since you have "input-name + option-value" and multiple selects can have the same value, and so on.  Is there a full example you would like to share?

Comment: The question contains an example for <select>. You are right. A <select multiple> should return a list.

Comment: @guettli Please review your question.  I do not think it contains what you think it contains :)  I can't re-read that question anymore.  I do hope you manage to add the desired logic, bs4 makes it fairly easy and is well documented, and should meet your needs with minimal personal effort.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank your. The initial question was unclear. I updated the question.

Comment: Typo in your new example.  `</texarea>` is missing the second `t`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, consider using `response.context` instead of `response.content`. As it is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.context), it gives you the template parameters that were used to render `response.content`. The form attributes you need (name and value) might be in there if you gave them as parameters to the renderer.

If you must use `response.content`, then I don't think Django provides a way to parse the HTML response. You can use a HTML parser like [beautifulsoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/), or do it using regular expressions.

Comment: Good point.  If its sufficient to look at the context and verify that the value was passed to the template as expected, then checking the context[var] is plenty.

Comment: For this particular question `response.content` is needed. Maybe the html got created by an other way. Maybe with `format_html()`, then there is no context.

Answer (score 2):

```
from collections import UserDict

class FormData(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frozen = False
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.frozen = True
        
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if self.frozen and key not in self:
            raise ValueError('Key %s is not in the dict. Available: %s' % (
                key, self.keys()
            ))
        super().__setitem__(key, value)

def parse_form(content):
    """
    Parse the first form in the html in content.
    """
    
    import lxml.html
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(content)
    return FormData(tree.forms[0].fields)
```

Example usage:

```
def test_foo_form(user_client):
    url = reverse('foo')
    response = user_client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    data = parse_form(response.content)
    response = user_client.post(url, data)
    assert response.status_code == 302
```

The above code is incomplete. Please don't copy+paste, but use the library: https://github.com/guettli/html_form_to_dict

Comment: @guetty ... May I ask: why not use BeautifulSoup instead? In general, I favour the minimalist approach and hate adding tools if non strictly required, particularly in the unit tests. However, everybody seems to agree that BeautifulSoup is the de-facto standard for HTML parsing in this context, and this might possibly be the very reason why parsing support hasn't been added to Django test client

Comment: @MarioOrlandi AFAIK BeautifulSoup is for parsing html which might be broken/invalid. In my case the html should be clean. If not, then I want to know that, since the html gets created by me. And AFAIK above BeautifulSoup solution only parses `input` elements, not <textarea> or <select>. Why do you think BS would be better?

Comment: I have no significant experience with BeautifulSoap, but just a few days ago I needed to parse the response content in a unit test; in my case, I had to check the classes of an HTML <table>; that's what I did: https://gist.github.com/morlandi/898f355b70a2845d2dd66e4bc686ff71

I like the jquery-like syntax for searching the DOM, since I'm already familiar with it; I guess you can similarly extract the value from a textarea or select; why do you think BS should be limited to input elements ?

Comment: Since HTML parsing is a common need when unit testing the frontend, I'm looking for a solution which doesn't force me to cluttered the code with too much helper functions, as they may be distracting.

Comment: @MarioOrlandi I found a simple solution with lxml (see above answer). If you think BS is better, then please provide a solution which works for textareas and select elements.

Comment: @guetty, I don't mind your solution. Actually, I like it very much. So simple and effective to collect all form fields in one shot.
Just wanted to hear your opinion about BS, since I'm considering whether to use it or not in unit tests ;)

Comment: I created a small library, so please the lib and don't copy+paste: https://github.com/guettli/html_form_to_dict

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, I tried to replicate with BeatifulSoap the solution proposed by guettli.

Here's what I came out:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def parse_form(content):
    data = {}
    html = BeautifulSoup(content, features="lxml")
    form = html.find('form', recursive=True)
    fields = form.find_all(('input', 'select', 'textarea'))
    for field in fields:
        name = field.get('name')
        if name:
            if field.name == 'input':
                value = field.get('value')
            elif field.name == 'select':
                try:
                    value = field.find_all('option', selected=True)[0].get('value')
                except:
                    value = None
            elif field.name == 'textarea':
                value = field.text
            else:
                # checkbox ? radiobutton ? file ? 
                continue
            data[name] = value
    return data
```

Is this a better result?

Honestly, I don't think so; on the other side, if you happen to use BS for parsing the response content in other ways, this might be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another version of returning form data from HTML input. It's copying the approach from [guettli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/633961)'s [html_to_dict](https://github.com/guettli/html_form_to_dict) package and lets you specify form lookup attributes.

A previous iteration I wrote using BeautifulSoup4 was more verbose than this implementation using lxml.

```py
import lxml.html

def parse_html_form(html: str, **kwargs) -> dict:
    """Returns form data as a dict.

    The form lookup can be narrowed down by using attributes to filter for
    as `kwargs`.
    """
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

    filter = " and ".join(f"@{key}='{val}'" for key, val in kwargs.items())
    form = tree.xpath(f"//form[{filter}]" if filter else "//form")[0]

    data = {}
    for key, element in form.inputs.items():
        match element.value:
            case lxml.html.CheckboxValues():
                data[key] = [sub.value for sub in element.value.group if sub.value]
            case lxml.html.MultipleSelectOptions():
                data[key] = list(element.value)
            case _:
                data[key] = element.value or ""
    return data
```

Here are the tests:

```html
@pytest.fixture
def dummy_forms():
    return """
    <html>
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="empty-text">
        <textarea name="textarea-with-whitespaces">\nmy textarea value</textarea>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-transport" value="car">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-transport" value="bike" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-transport" value="train" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-transport" value="foot" checked>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-food-unchecked" value="eggplant">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-food-unchecked" value="mushrooms">

        <input type="radio" name="radio-contact" value="email">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-contact" value="phone" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-contact" value="mail">

        <input type="hidden" name="hidden-csrftoken" value="123456">

        <select name="select-single-icecream">
         <option value="chocolate">Chocolate</option>
         <option value="vanilla" selected>Vanilla</option>
         <option value="strawberry">Strawberry</option>
        </select>

        <select name="select-multiple-bicycles" multiple>
         <option value="roadbike" selected>Road bike</option>
         <option value="cargobike" selected>Cargo bike</option>
         <option value="recumbentbike">Recumbent bike</option>
         <option value="tallbike">Tall bike</option>
        </select>
      </form>

      <form name="my-other-form-name">
        <input type="hidden" name="by-name" value="true">
      </form>

      <form id="my-other-form-id">
        <input type="hidden" name="by-id" value="true">
      </form>
    </html>"""
```

```py
def test_parse_html_form(dummy_forms):
    assert parse_html_form(dummy_forms) == {
        "empty-text": "",
        "textarea-with-whitespaces": "\nmy textarea value",
        "checkbox-transport": ["bike", "train", "foot"],
        "checkbox-food-unchecked": [],
        "radio-contact": "phone",
        "hidden-csrftoken": "123456",
        "select-single-icecream": "vanilla",
        "select-multiple-bicycles": ["roadbike", "cargobike"],
    }
    assert parse_html_form(dummy_forms, name="my-other-form-name") == {"by-name": "true"}
    assert parse_html_form(dummy_forms, id="my-other-form-id") == {"by-id": "true"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tool [mechanize](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) provides a browser-like interface to test forms:

> Stateful programmatic web browsing in Python. Browse pages programmatically with easy HTML form filling and clicking of links.

This snippet from the docs contains an example how to fill a form:

```
import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("http://www.example.com/")
# follow second link with element text matching regular expression
response1 = br.follow_link(text_regex=r"cheese\s*shop", nr=1)
print(br.title())
print(response1.geturl())
print(response1.info())  # headers
print(response1.read())  # body

br.select_form(name="order")
# Browser passes through unknown attributes (including methods)
# to the selected HTMLForm.
br["cheeses"] = ["mozzarella", "caerphilly"]  # (the method here is __setitem__)
# Submit current form.  Browser calls .close() on the current response on
# navigation, so this closes response1
response2 = br.submit()
```

This works fine if JavaScript support is not needed.